# ElevateZoom default zoom level

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, elevatezoom

I can't find how to change the default zoom level of elevateZoom, any suggestions? This is my code:

```
$('.img-zoom').elevateZoom({
    responsive: true,
    zoomWindowWidth:500,
    zoomWindowHeight:300,
    zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
    zoomWindowFadeOut: 750,
    scrollZoom : true
  });
```

Comment: By default elevateZoom sets the zoom to 1, to change it just use the property:
zoomLevel: n

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the zoomLevel example is hidden on elevateZoom's [example page](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#zoom-level), but if you use dev tools you can remove the `display: none` and find the following  info:

> **Zoom Level**
>   The zoomlevel by default is 1, but this can be overridden
>   You can do this with the `zoomLevel` config option
>   Zoom Level 2 would make the image twice as small
>   Zoom Level 0.5 would make the image twice as big

```
$("#zoom_11").elevateZoom({
  zoomLevel: 2
});
```

Comment: it's not working bro ? how can i set extra zoom in my image hover ?

Answer (score 0):

for those who don't know why "zoomLevel" is not working. you should also set "scrollZoom" to "true".

```
$(".img-zoom").elevateZoom({
  scrollZoom: true,
  zoomLevel: 0.8
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still trying to make ElevateZoom work, it won't work, it's dead project. Use this fork instead:
https://igorlino.github.io/elevatezoom-plus/index.html